# Как организовать навигацию в приложении с единой операцией, сохранив логику анимаций?

Tags: android, single-activity

Есть пробное Single Activity приложение, состоящее из одной Activity и четырёх фрагментов, причём ни один из этих фрагментов не содержит внутри себя других фрагментов.

В Activity есть только контейнер для одного фрагмента: FrameLayout на весь экран.

В первом, втором и третьем фрагментах находится по кнопке, при нажатии на которую пользователь переходит на следующий фрагмент(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 - 4), причём каждый переход вперёд по стеку сопровождается уникальной анимацией(`setCustomAnimations`), равно как и переход назад. То есть реализуется шесть анимаций.

Вопрос в том, как правильно и грамотно организовать и собрать в одно месте навигацию, сохранив при этом все анимации.

У меня есть работающее решение, но оно тупое во всех смыслах слова. Внутри каждого фрагмента я реализовал интерфейс `Router`, который по клику на кнопку передаёт событие в Activity, в котором осуществляется переход:

```
packContentFragment.setRouter(() ->
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, new NextFragment())
        .addToBackStack("2")
        .commit());
```

И такая запись у меня для каждого фрагмента. В `onBackPressed` аналогичная куча мала:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
           //поиск по тегу и захардкоденный переход
        }
    }
```

Я пробовал использовать `Cicerone`, но реализовав его я не смогу использовать анимации, т.к для анимации мне нужен `FragmentManager`, которого нет в презентере.

Comment: посмотрите Navigation DrawerActivity

Comment: [Navigation Architecture Component](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/416025/) разработан специально для таких целей. В качестве "действия" каждого отдельного перехода вы можете указать любую логику, как и анимацию

Answer (score 0):

что мешает в активити в onStart помещать FragmentManager в презентер, при onStop обнулять?

по идее роутер должен быть реализован отдельной сущностью интерактор который будет на вход принимать новый фрагмент для отображения, брать с активити текущий фрагмент и в зависимотси от этого выставлять нужную анимацию и собственно все